# How to create a table identical to other table in structure and constraints in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want to create a table (lets say table_copy) which has same columns as other table (lets call it table_original) in Oracle database, so the query will be like this :

```
create table table_copy as (select * from table_original where 1=0);
```

This will create a table, but the constraints of table_original are not copied to table_copy, so what should be done in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Only `NOT NULL` constraints are copied using Create Table As Syntax (CTAS). Others should be created manually.

You might however query data dictionary view to see the definitions of constraints and implement them on your new table using PL/SQL.

The other tool that might be helpful is Oracle Data Pump. You could import the table using `REMAP_TABLE` option specifying the name for the new table.

Comment: It's Create Table As Select actually.

Answer (score 2):

Use a database tool to extract the DDL needed for the constraints (SQL Developer does the job). Edit the resulting script to match the name of the new class.

Execute the script.

If you need to do this programmatically you can use a statement like this:

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','PERSON') from DUAL;
```